# Conditional Association In Doctrine2

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, associations

I have just run myself into this tricky situation.
I have an entity called Gift.

Now the gift entity needs to have a field called `receiver` which can be associated with 2 entities `RegisteredUser` entity OR `Guest` entity.

The problem here is now how do I define the association for the receiver field!!

I thought of creating an entity called `GiftReceiver` use inheritance mapping but I cannot map the discriminator to a class which does not extend GiftReceiver.

Am I going the wrong way? Is there a good way to implement this?
Thanks in advance for your help!! :)

Comment: You want a single property to be mapped to 2 entities? Maybe you should map it to a common super class instead!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about making a subclass of `User` as `Guest` and you can just map the receiver field to `User` entity.
When you fetch the receiver entity on the `Gift`, doctrine will fetch the appropriate object `Guest` or `RegisteredUser`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could put logic into your entity, that returns either a `Guest` or a `RegisteredUser`, both implementing the same interface called `GiftReceiver`.

```
class Gift {

    // mapped to guest; nullabe true
    protected $guest;

    // mapped to registeredUser; nullabe true
    protected $registeredUser;


    public function getReceiver()
    {
        return $this->getGuest() ?: $this->getRegisteredUser();
    }

    // getters/setters ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating something like a `GiftIntermediary` entity. with the following fields:

```
Receiver
RegisteredUser 
Guest
```

Then apply the following associations:

```
Gift.Receiver = GiftIntermediary.Receiver
RegisteredUser.ID = GiftIntermediary.RegisteredUser 
Guest.ID = GiftIntermediary.Guest
```

Here is a sample query to gather data from the above associations:

```
SELECT Gift.*, RegisteredUser.*, Guest.*
FROM Guest INNER JOIN (RegisteredUser INNER JOIN (Gift INNER JOIN GiftIntermediary ON Gift.Receiver = GiftIntermediary.Receiver) ON RegisteredUser.ID = GiftIntermediary.RegisteredUser) ON Guest.ID = GiftIntermediary.Guest
```